# Qualtrics Drag-and-Drop: Allowing several groups per Items

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable, qualtrics, jquery-ui-droppable

When using the Pick, Group and Rank Question in Qualtrics, I would like to allow an item to be dropped to several groups if wanted.

How is this possible, e.g., with using Javascript?

In the default Pick, Group and Rank question, every item can only be dropped to one group or bucket and then vanishes from the item list on the left-hand-side.

I found also this same question in the [qualtrics community](https://community.qualtrics.com/XMcommunity/discussion/18570/pick-group-and-rank-question) but it appears to not been answered.

Context: Qualtrics allows to easily embed JavaScript code to a question to be inserted in the following placeholders via the Survey user iterface.

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
    /*Place your JavaScript here to run when the page loads*/
});

Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnReady(function()
{
    /*Place your JavaScript here to run when the page is fully displayed*/
});

});

Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnUnload(function()
{
    /*Place your JavaScript here to run when the page is unloaded*/
});
```

Comment: It's not possible.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you T. Gibbons for your comment.
An alternative could be then to add separate buckets/groups for each combination of "single topic" buckets/groups. However, doing so seems to complicate the UX to respond to the question.

Comment: It seemed counter-intuitive to me that despite the flexibility of Qualtrics to add JavaScript code, this - let's say - "repeated pick, drag and drop" is not possible. But there may be reasons why this is the case..